# URL changed but component was not rendered. Just work correctly after reload page

Tags: angular, routes

My routing module setup

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
{
        path: '', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: HomeComponent,
},

{
        path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit', component: EditComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':username', component: UserComponent
            }
}
```

*Profile.component.html*

```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After I login my app success, server response an user and I use `BehaviorSubject` to emit new user

In navbar component, I subscribe and store it to property *user*

*Auth Service*

```
   user = new BehaviorSubject(null)
   login() { 
      this.http.post('/api/login', {username, password})
      .subscribe((userResponse) => this.user.next(userResponse))
   }
```

*App.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

*App.component.ts*

```
isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.user
      .subscribe((user) => {
        if (user === null) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
        else {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
      })
  }
```

*Navbar.component.html*

```
   <a routerLink="/" class="pt-3 pb-3 pl-4 pr-4 active">Home</a>
   <a [routerLink]="['/profile', user.username]" class="pt-3 pb-3 pl-4 pr-4">Profile</a>
```

The problem is when I click Profile, the url in address bar change to /profile/abc as expected, the *AuthGuard* also worked and return true but the *UserComponent* was not rendered . I still stay in *HomeComponent*

However when I F5 the page, the UserComponent loaded and the navbar route work perfectly.

I think the problem is in my `App-routing.module.ts` or `routerLink`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I updated this post. I also tested log user when I click *Profile* in *Navbar* and the *user* was logged correctly

Comment: Any Errors in the console?

Comment: No sir. I put console log in ```AuthGuard```, ```UserComponent```, after I click I see only 'Auth guard worked' in console. Then I reload page I see 'Auth guard worked' and 'User component init'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `app.component.html` should look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the `<router-outlet>` should be loaded on startup.

Comment: The `<router-outlet>` should be outside, on startup